# P&T Assets field "loses" image when editing from some machines

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, image

An image is stored in a P&T Assets field and has been working fine. An editor emailed me saying when she opens an entry to edit it, the image is gone. I tried to edit entries and it worked fine. I even logged in as her and used the same browser and it worked. I then watched her edit it on her computer (Win 7 with Firefox) and sure enough, the image is not there when she opens the edit page.

I made sure she was using the right url, https (and not http which caused problems), no domain mismatches, etc.

A strange problem to start with, the inconsistency makes it even more 'fun'.

Comment: Have you been able to determine which browser and platform combination this occurs on? If it exists on Win 7 & Firefox is the issue the same on Mac and Firefox? Can you try other browsers on Win 7 to see if it's one or all? This will help to pinpoint the issue and aid in providing a solution.

Comment: Does the editor in question here have troubles using a different browser? Maybe she has some extensions installed on her Firefox which are doing this?

Comment: We figured it out. It was only happening on random people's machines. I then remembered a similar issue where the field would not work (clicking add file would do nothing). It was related to the URL in use didn't match the URL in the cp settings. The same was happening here. They were logging in at https://www.example.com/system/....and not https://www.example.com/admin.php. Once they log in at the right url (admin and not system) all was well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out. It was only happening on random people's machines. They were logging in at example.com/system/....and not example.com/admin.php (masked cp access). Once they log in at the right url (admin.php and not system) all was well.

So the domain (www/dev/secure/etc), http and https, and the segment after the tld (system folder path or masked cp access) can all cause these problems.